# How to reset CSS3 *-transform: translate(…)?

Tags: css, reset, css-transforms

How can I reset CSS `transform` properties CSS `translate` value?

#### Say I have:

```css
div.someclass {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,- 50%);
         -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
            transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

Then how do I clear all transformations/translations?

---

**Should I use:** `translate(0, 0);` / `translate3d(0, 0, 0);` **or** `transform:auto;` ?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform), the [Initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial_value) is `none`.

**You can reset the transformation using:**

```css
div.someclass {
    transform: none;
}
```

---

**Using vendor prefix:**

```css
div.someclass {
    -webkit-transform: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-transform: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: none; /* IE 9 */
         -o-transform: none; /* Opera */
            transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Safari iOS 10.3, 11.0 and Safari 11 on macOS didn't actually reset the transformation properly with `-webkit-transform: none;` or `transform: none;`
I had to instead reset all the values I changed with the transform property so  essentially I think the first option

```
translate(0, 0); / translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

is the way to go for browser compatibility for now.
So this SHOULD work:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: none;
-ms-transform: none;
-o-transform: none;
transform: translate(0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this problem still exists in Safari iOS 14.0 in 2021. No need for prefixes now, but `transform: none` doesn't take effect immediately; `transform: translate(0px)` does work, even to cancel another type of transform such as a rotation. Safari's behaviour was baffling me until I found this question and answer;  `transform: none` seems to work with every other browser I have tried.