# Is there a CSS3 Reset?

Tags: css, css-reset

I am simply wondering if there exists a global CSS reset for CSS3. Something along the lines of the commonly-used versions created by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), but for CSS3 specifically. I've queried channels such as Google, Github and here on SO, but haven't come across a comprehensive solution.

**Edit**:
The term "reset" is probably misleading since it deals mainly with resetting browser default settings. "Recalibration" may be better suited.

I should clarify and put forth a use case.

This would work in tandem with the normal CSS reset yet also handle any styling caused by rotation, box shadow, animation, border radius, etc. For example, as mentioned before on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790617/resetting-css3-transform-translate):

```
-webkit-transform:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:none; /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:none; /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:none; /* Opera */
transform:none;
```

The above snippet, and others like it, would be associated with any HTML tags that might get affected by them, as it is with current CSS resets.

The implementation need for this would probably not be too common if you are in control of your properties. However if you are, for example, creating an app or plug-in that will be used across different domains, where the styling of the pages the plug-in script is invoked on can influence that of the plug-in itself, then something like this would be very useful.

I realize there are other ways to tame CSS inheritance and handle cross-domain issues, but this question is put forth regarding the CSS3 reset directly.

Much thanks.

Comment: As if prefixes weren't unwieldy enough by themselves already...

Comment: Is there any tag that sets CSS transforms by default? I don't see why resetting this kind of thing.

Comment: I can't see how this would be helpful. Why are you asking for this? There's probably a reason you can't find an existing solution...

Comment: I agree with @bfavaretto ... I don't think this is really necessary. Are you having an issue that you need to reset these styles?

Comment: I agree with each of you, and in my particular case, whereby we have a script that generates html within an iframe that can be run anywhere, I just created the resets manually. Yes - things like box shadow and transform were affecting the iframe itself, which just got me wondering if there were other, more comprehensive solutions out there, that might catch CSS3 behaviors I may have unwittingly left out.

Comment: What browser is setting box shadow and transform on an `iframe` by default?

Comment: It wasn't so much as a default setting or a browser issue, actually. We encountered situations where, when our script was invoked on a page that had some custom styling on the iframe tag - using !important by the way - and it cascaded to the iframe generated by our plug-in.

Comment: Google shows various results for [**CSS3 Reset**](http://www.google.com/search?q=CSS3+Reset). Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real way to solve your problem is either to use the `scoped` attribute, or to create your widget using the Shadow DOM.

This way, you can insulate yourself from external CSS. Unfortunately, neither are really ready for use, so yes, you'll have to manually protect yourself.

The alternative is to set everything (transform, font-size, padding, etc) in your code with `!important`, rather than resetting it to 0/none, then setting it anew.

Comment: Very enlightening. Shadow DOM and scoped attribute - will have to look into those and implement when they are stable. Thanks.